# Robot framework Wait until page does not contain takes 15 seconds

Tags: selenium, wait, robotframework

I'm trying to use the Robot Framewrok function Wait Until Page Does Not Contain, but no matter what timeout i set - it always waits for 15 seconds.
With function Page should not contain it's even worse - 30 seconds.

For example

```
Wait Until Page Does Not Contain     x     5s
```

When function fails it says: The text x didn't disappear in 5 seconds.
But it takes 15 seconds to finish

I've tried with Set selenium timeout and written something like this

```
Wait until page doesnt contain
    [Arguments]    ${text}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds     2s      1s      page should not contain     ${text}
```

But it always takes longer than expected

Where's the problem?

Comment: Did you set the implicit wait of the driver to 1s? or Set it to 0s

Comment: Do you mean Set selenium timeout method? I've tried with multiple values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to omit this problem by writing keyword

```
Page shouldnt contain
    [Arguments]    ${text}
    ${pageSource} =  get source
    should not contain  ${pageSource}   ${text}
```

Easy, but not so obvious